# Hot cup on wood made mark

Tags: wood, damage

I'm in trouble, I put this mark on an antique cupboard by putting a lot cup on it, is there anything I can try to make it go away?

[image]

Comment: Sand and stain.

Answer (score 1):

I had a wooden countertop in my island with this same issue and one trick I found was if you put a teatowel over the area and then with an iron on low hold it a ways above the towel and move it around over the area.  Be careful not to get too close or too hot or you could make the mark worse.  Did this successfully to a good half dozen 'hot rings' on the counter.